# SQLite3, I need groupby on two columns where the combination of them should be unique

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table chats, with columns sender, receiver....
For example I have below data:

> **sender  receiver**
>    id1    id2
>    id1    id3
>    id2    id1
>    id3    id2
>    id2    id3
>    id3    id2

I want result as

> **sender  receiver**
>    id1    id2
>    id1    id3
>    id3    id2

Please suggest how I could use GROUP BY sender, receiver.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<` or `>` so only one combination of sender and receiver gets selected.

```
select * from chats 
where sender < receiver --or sender > receiver
order by sender,receiver
```

Comment: Thanks @vkp, this is what I was looking for :)